# How do I share a cache across Node workers with Redis?

Tags: node.js, caching, express, redis

Forgive me if this is a really dumb question. I have been googling for the past hour and can't seem to find it answered anywhere.

Our application needs to query our CMS database every hour or so to update all of its non-user-specfic CMS content. I would like to store that data in one place and have all the workers have access to it - w/o each worker having to call the API every hour. Also I would like this cache to persist in the event of a node worker crash. Since we're pretty new to node here I predict we might have some of those.

I will handle all the cache expiration logic. I just want a store that can be shared between users, can handle worker crashing and restarting, and is at the application level - not the user level. So user sessions are no good for this.

Is Redis even what I'm looking for? Sadly it may be too late to install mongo on our web layer for this release anyway. Pub/sub looks promising but really seems like it's made for messaging - not a shared cache. Maybe I am reading that wrong though.

Thank you so much stack overflow! I promise to be a good citizen now that I have registered.

Comment: I don’t know the gritty details of your system, but this sounds fine. It’s okay for multiple Node.js servers to query the same Redis server. The main advantage of Mongo (in this situation, as a cache) is that Mongo has a mature cluster capability so you don’t have a single point of failure. But Redis is probably faster, and is easier to configure.

Comment: So are you saying pub/sub is the way to go for a shared application-level cache, or is there some easier method I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Redis is a great solution for your problem. Not sure why you are considering pub/sub though. Doesn't sound like the workers need to be notified when the cache is updated, they just need to be able to read the latest value written to the cache. You can use a simple string value in redis for this stored under a consistent key.

In summary, you'd have a process that would update a redis key (say, `cms-cache-stuff`) every hour. Each worker which needs that data will just GET `cms-cache-stuff` from redis every time it needs that cached info.

This solution will survive both the cache refresh process crashing or workers crashing, since the key in redis will always have data in it (though that data will be stale if the refresh process doesn't come back up).

If for some wild reason you don't want the workers continually reading from redis (why not? its plenty fast enough) you could still store the latest cached data in `cms-cache-stuff` and then publish a message through pub/sub to your workers letting them know the cache is updated, so they can read `cms-cache-stuff` again. This gives you durability and recovery, since crashed workers can just read `cms-cache-stuff` again at startup and then start listening on the pub/sub channel for additional updates.

Pub/sub alone is pretty useless for caching since it provides no durability. If a worker is crashed and not listening on the channel, the messages are simply discarded.

Answer (score 0):

Well as I suspected my problem was a super-basic noob mistake that's hard to even even explain well enough to get the "duh" answer. I was using [the connect-redis package](https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis), which is really designed for sessions, not a cache. Once someone pointed to [node_redis client](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) I was able to pretty easily get it set up and do what I wanted to do.

Thanks a lot - hopefully this helps some redis noob in the future!